# Call Image From Formula

Tags: google-sheets, formula

If Statement Formula not working to call a specific image based on specific text in an adjacent cell.

This works:

```
    `=if(istext(A2), image("https://img.labnol.org/di/high-quality-  photo.jpg",2),"")`
```

This is not Working but is what is needed:

```
        `=IF(istext(A2="Van", image("https://img.labnol.org/di/high-quality-photo.jpg",2),IF(A2="Bike", image("https://isome other image from the library",2),""))`
```

[Image Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kVdBm8eyBXe8-74NMSAk5IVfQvzLWK4E5up_un_KLgk/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `istext(A2="Van"` to `=if(find("Van",A3)>0, image("https://img.labnol.org/di/high-quality-photo.jpg",2),"")`

Comment: See this spreadsheet to build on from above: [Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18Uivo2Ar5rr8GTb6KHnPplOy4LeSTUVzluERMQQz1kk/copy)